# Convert Julian Date to solar Date in javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

I want to convert Gregorian date into solar Date in JavaScript
I have an idea about this issue but I can not implement it. I perform a lot about this issue but none were completed,
Please guide me about this issue.
Thanks

Comment: I think `Gregorian` date is `solar` Date and `Julian` date is `Lunar` date.

Comment: I think I've got it
But thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Gregorian date is solar Date and Julian date is Lunar date, anyways, [here is a converter](http://jesusnjim.com/common/julian-gregorian.html) that has these functions, I didn't try it but you may download it and may be this will help you.

```
function JulianToGregorianY(JulianDate); // returns Gregorian Year given Julian date
function JulianToGregorianMo(JulianDate) //returns Gregorian Month given Julian date
function JulianToGregorianD(JulianDate) //returns Gregorian Day given Julian date
function JulianToGregorianH(JulianDate) //returns Gregorian Hour given Julian date
function JulianToGregorianMi(JulianDate) //returns Gregorian Minutes given Julian date
function JulianToGregorianS(JulianDate) //returns Gregorian Seconds given Julian date
function JulianToGregorianMs(JulianDate) //returns Gregorian Milliseconds given Julian date
function JulianToGregorianFracSec(JulianDate) // returns Gregorian Seconds (fractional) given
```